# fetch mysql prepared statement as array of hashes

Tags: mysql, ruby, arrays, hash, prepared-statement

I'm struggling with ruby's mysql gem and prepares statements.
I want to end up with the same as I would do with `each_hash` over the result, but it's nor supported in prepares statements.
So I came with this horrible mess.

```
  stmt = @db.prepare("SELECT mat_id, name, qty FROM materials WHERE mat_id = ? ")

  #those 3 lines hurt my eyes
  res = stmt.execute(params[:id])
  mat_id, name, qty  =  res.bind_result(Integer, String, Integer).fetch
  @material = [mat_id: mat_id, name: name, qty: qty]
```

There has to be a better way to fetch the results and get an array of hashes.

A better mysql gem could be a valid answer. An ORM is NOT.

Comment: Have you tried `mysql2` gem?

Comment: An ORM might not be a valid answer, but you should still look into the Sequel gem. It's the only ORM I'm aware of that an SQL junky will feel comfortable with.

Comment: Why is an ORM not a valid answer? Not all are alike and, though some are poorly done, others like Sequel, are amazingly flexible and powerful and can ease your programming burden significantly. Looking at your code I can see where it'd help. http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/prepared_statements_rdoc.html

Comment: @SergioTulentsev mysql2 doesn't support prepared statements

Comment: @theTinMan This is a proof of concept Of course this will be nowhere near the final program. I don't want to use an ORM because of the way they get entangled into the model. If I'm doing a unit test, the database MUST NOT be touched, and all ORM force you to do that.

Comment: This is what I mean with an entangled class `class Comment < Sequel::Model(:something)
  table_name # => :something
end`

Comment: @Denis give me a way to dissociate the model from the ORM and we can talk :-) The way the ORM's are used goes against every single book about a proper unit test. (they should be small, fast, and NEVER EVER touch a database or the filesystem)

Comment: @TheDisintegrator: I fail to see how your query is any less dissociated than the example query I posted. But I suppose I'm missing something.

Comment: @Denis my comment is from before your answer. The idea Is to have MaterialsStorage, MateRialsStorageDB and MateRialsStorageStub so I can inject the one I need into Materials. During Unit test I could use MateRialsStorageStub and in production MateRialsStorageDB (proxy pattern). I'm looking into sequel right now to see if it really supports prepared statements ...

Comment: @TheDisintegrator: Sequel isn't so much of an ORM as it is a tool to manipulate abstract syntax trees. Basically, it allows you to manipulate the SQL grammar using ruby, and it generates the query you want when you issue the fetch, insert, etc. the ORM part, which you referred to, is completely orthogonal to that functionality. Think of Sequel as a more advanced and rubyish SQL gem, and you'll see the light. It's an amazing piece of software, and I'm unaware of any equivalent in other languages.

Comment: @denis: I had a near death experience some months ago. I don't want to see the light ever again :-) :-| :-\  I'm looking into sequel. Let's see if it works. But anyway, this is now a personal matter. Is HAS to be a more rubyish way to express those tree lines for the fetching.

Comment: @The Disintegrator: I ran into this same problem and shared my solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing the comments, I'll still post the Sequel link as an answer:

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/

You don't need to use the model part of Sequel at all. In fact, the docs has an entire section dedicated to SQL junkies:

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html

example query:

```
DB.fetch("SELECT * FROM albums WHERE name LIKE ?", 'A%') do |row|
  puts row[:name]
end
```

Comment: Ok, you win. Using sequel now. Still with a bitter taste for not being able to find a better way to express the three code lines of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner!

```
Hash[stmt.result_metadata.fetch_fields.map(&:name).zip( stmt.fetch )]
```

Or more robust

```
row = stmt.fetch
Hash[stmt.result_metadata.fetch_fields.map(&:name).zip( row )] if row
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://tmtm.org/en/mysql/ruby/, results have an "each_hash" method, but statements don't.  What a pain in the ass...

```
#A proxy for the statement class
class Stmt

  def each_hash
    fields = @target.result_metadata.fetch_fields.map do |f| f.name.to_sym end 
    @target.execute.each do |x| 
      hash = {}
      fields.zip(x).each do |pair|
        hash[pair[0]] = pair[1]
      end 
      yield hash
    end 
  end 

  def initialize(target)
    @target = target
  end 

  def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
    @target.send(name, *args, &block)
  end 
end
```

Now, you can do this:

```
Stmt.new(@db.prepare(...).execute(...)).each_hash do |x|
  puts x
end
```

and you can loop through each row as a hash.

I still haven't tested this for multiple executions